# How to retrieve data from this list

Tags: python

This list how to retrieve only problems by using python.

```
[{"ordination": [{"condition": "system_drive_free_space < 10000","match": true,"problems": [{"id": "disk_cleanup","point": "/remote_action/disk_cleanup/hgk5255sfghjkd516465s"
}]},{"condition": "total_drive_free_space < 20000","match": true,"problems": [{ "id": "disk_cleanup","point": "/remote_action/disk_cleanup/h41525c274558hgfdbd3b"}]}]},{
"ordination": [{"condition": "\"action:Get Startup Impact/HighImpactCount\" > 0","match": true}]},{"ordination": [{"condition": "average_network_response_time > 30000",
"match": true},{"condition": "network_availability_level != high","match": true}] }]
```

For example the output like this

```
 "problems": [{"id": "disk_cleanup","point": "/remote_action/disk_cleanup/hgk5255sfghjkd516465s" }]
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Please add your code to rhe question.

Comment: From the list i want get output as Problems and their parameters

Comment: [Edit] your question to include python code you've been trying to use so far

Comment: .for example the output like this "problems": [{"id": "disk_cleanup","point": "/remote_action/disk_cleanup/hgk5255sfghjkd516465s" }]

Answer (score 0):

if your data is in a variable named `data`, then try this:

```
for item in data:    
    for inside_item in item.get("ordination", []):
        for inside_value in inside_item.get("problems", []):
            print(inside_value[0]["id"])
```

Comment: Why not use `item.get("ordination", [])`?

Comment: @OneCricketeer yes, that would be a shorter answer, thnx. I updated my answer.

Comment: {'id': 'disk_cleanup', 'point': '/remote_action/disk_cleanup/hgk5255sfghjkd516465s'}in this output i want only 'id'...how to get this

Comment: @code It's a dictionary. Do you understand how to parse a dictionary?

Comment: @codeanalyzer  you mean the value of `id` like `disk_cleanup` only? OR the whole thing as a dictionary like a `{'id': 'disk_cleanup'}`

Comment: Do you mean the value of id like disk_cleanup only...yes

Comment: @codeanalyzer I changed the code as your wish.

Comment: @codeanalyzer if this worked for you please mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: ya ....Thank you for the solution I marked .

Answer (score 0):

you can try something

```
items = [{"ordination": [{"condition": "system_drive_free_space < 10000", "match": True, "problems": [
        {"id": "disk_cleanup", "point": "/remote_action/disk_cleanup/hgk5255sfghjkd516465s"}]},
                         {"condition": "total_drive_free_space < 20000", "match": True, "problems": [
                             {"id": "disk_cleanup", "point": "/remote_action/disk_cleanup/h41525c274558hgfdbd3b"}]}]},
         {"ordination": [{"condition": "action: Get Startup Impact / HighImpactCount> 0", "match": True}]},
         {"ordination": [{"condition": "average_network_response_time > 30000", "match": True},
                            {"condition": "network_availability_level != high", "match": True}]}]
for item in items:
    for ordination in item['ordination']:
        print(ordination.get('problems'))
```

It prints `None` for `ordination`s without `problems`.

Comment: It prints `None` for `ordination`s without `problems`.

Comment: Thanks @Shireen, updated in answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

If that array is stored in a variable called `list`, (e.g. `list = [{ordination...`) then you can use this code to retrieve the value of problems:

```
problems = list[0].get("ordination")[0].get("problems")
print(problems)
```

This should print out the list which is stored the problems section.